# Scalable ASP.NET application jobs synchronization

Tags: asp.net, azure, synchronization, soa, jobs

My ASP.NET app can run *on multiple virtual servers* (e.g. in Azure I can scale on demand). I'm not sure where I will host my app, whether it will be Azure or some other hosting service, but I faced with the following problem: 
**I need to run jobs on some schedule**: get exchange rates and they should be available for all server instances, check database and send emails, manage app cache or logs or do some other jobs in background. 
What I don't understand well is how to build/architecture the system so that **those jobs are executed only once** (*I don't want to pull exchange rates on every app instance or send emails more than once*). So simple use cases of some Quartz.NET or QueueBackgroundWorkItem don't suit me.
I know that **Azure WebJobs** is capable of doing such things, but I do want the solution that **doesn't not depend on hosting service** like Azure, because maybe tomorrow I will want to move to another hosting service.

- **Is there any generic solution for this kind of problem?**
- **Can I build this using service bus that is not related to any hosting service?**
- **What are the advantages of using Azure specific solution (WebJobs, Azure ServiceBus) instead of generic solutions?**
- **What are the best practices to build this part of application so I can replace it in a quick way using DI? Just abstract away the service bus using interfaces or something else should be done?**

Thanks.

Comment: Azure web jobs are not only azure specific, they are available in Project Kudu, so you can host your own web jobs with Kudu, Kudu is the engine azure is using and it is open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at NServiceBus (and the [Particular Service Platform](http://particular.net/))? It can be used as a deployment-agnostic API for asynchronous message processing and deployed both to Azure as well as on your own servers.

When run on Azure, it leverages Azure Service Bus and when on your own server farm, you can choose MSMQ, RabbitMQ, and even SQL tables as your transport.

NServiceBus leverages dependency injection quite heavily so testing your solution is very easy.

Hope that helps.

- Full disclosure: I'm the original author of NServiceBus and lead its' current development.

Comment: I looked at NServiceBus and I actually like it. What stops me to use it is its expensive price, because I want a free solution for this kind of task. But I also see that NServiceBus provides free license for small startups, and as I'm developing my website on my own, maybe it also can be treated as startup project. Will contact your support in order to know if my project suits startup licence. Thanks!